# How can you construct a right triangle, ABC with a right angle in C, if you are given the hypotenuse, c, and the altitude of the point C?

Tags: triangles, geometric-construction

How can you construct a right triangle, $\triangle ABC$ with a right angle in $C$, if you are given the hypotenuse, $c$, and the altitude of the point $C$?

I know it's very basic but I just can't seem to figure this out - I've tried everything I can think of, started from both $h_c$ and $c$ - but I keep getting stuck.

[image]

Apologies for the poor formatting, it's my first post here.
I'm sorry for asking such a basic question. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Thank you so much for the help! I know the guidelines about schoolwork questions, but I'm really struggling with construction so I thought I'd give it a shot.
Again, I'm very grateful for the help, thank you Narasimham and Michael Burr for answering/commenting! You really did help!
All the best!

Comment: When you say construct, do you mean construct with straight-edge and compass or find the lengths of the legs?  Either way, the secret is that all three triangles in your image are similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a compass draw a semicircle with AB as diameter = 2r  and next draw  a straight line parallel to AB at given altitude h<r intersecting the semicircle at two points.

Join AC1,BC1, so there are two solution constructions. You can label second vertex as C2, (a,b) between AC2,BC2.